# Specify an intent on the ask function

Tags: actions-on-google

I would like to know, how to specify the function of redirection in the ask function.
Like :

1. Launch main function to choice the actions.
2. Start the function chosen by the user.
3. Loop in this function as long as the user does not say "stop" for example.

Maybe with a specific intent in the ask function, I don't know ...
Does anyone have the solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your request is what [contexts](https://dialogflow.com/docs/contexts) are used for in Dialogflow. You can set it up so that certain intents are only available to be triggered if a certain input context exists. These contexts originate from an output context of an intent.

Using the dialog state is not recommended. If you want to store generic data, you should use `app.data` in v1 or `conv.data` in v2 of the AoG client library. This [data object](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/save-data) persists throughout a session, which is more powerful than dialog state.

Comment: I don't use Dialogflow. I use the Actions SDK

Comment: If you aren't using Dialogflow, you can still use the `app.data` object to store this data throughout the session.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The ask() method is "completed" in the text intent. It is a shame that you can't - the code would be so much less cluttered if you could.

IAC, you can pass "dialog state" to ask() and then getDialogState() in the text intent and use that to restore your application's context and continue from there.